# Securing React application with in-memory JWT token

Tags: reactjs, jwt, single-sign-on, keycloak, create-react-app

I configured my React SPA to work with Keycloak using a "Public" SSO client.

I'm storing the JWT Access Token inside the Redux store (dev-tools disabled in production).

I'm not storing anything inside the Local Storage, Session Storage or as a Cookie.

Since my token is inside the Redux store, it's fair to say that the token is stored in-memory (on page refresh you will be briefly redirected back to Keycloak).

Following [this documentation page from Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/secure/security-guidance/data-security/token-storage#browser-in-memory-scenarios):

> Auth0 recommends storing tokens in browser memory as the most secure option. Using Web Workers to handle the transmission and storage of tokens is the best way to protect the tokens, as Web Workers run in a separate global scope than the rest of the application. Use Auth0 SPA SDK whose default storage option is in-memory storage leveraging Web Workers. If you cannot use Web Workers, Auth0 recommends as an alternative that you use JavaScript closures to emulate private methods.

So, in my case, I'm using "JavaScript closures to emulate private methods" approach (CRA).

The Redux store is not publicly accessible and the React process is contained within the JavaScript memory at runtime.

I'm also enforcing HTTPS, I added [Node Helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/helmet) and I have a quite strong CSP policy both inside Keycloak and React application. Not to mention that my "Public" SSO client is very restrictive in terms of "Web Origins" and "Redirect URLs".

I think my solution is pretty secure and solid, but other people thinks differently.

What do you think?

Comment: As long as the token is in the browser it is vulnerable to XSS attacks. Making sure your code follows all the best practices to mitigate XSS is more important than obscuring the handling of the token. Enforcing HTTPS, CSP, or being restrictive about Origin and redirects doesn't give you much more protection from XSS. In my opinion, it's better to keep the tokens from the browser at all and use session cookies. At least as long as the browsers don't give us a secure way of storing tokens.

Comment: @MichalTrojanowski thanks for your answer! If your website is the victim of an XSS attack, the application will already be compromised quite badly, as the malicious script will be able to: take snapshots of the DOM (and send them to a 3rd party server) and much more (i.e: executing code server-side). I'm thinking that the token will be the least of your problems.

Comment: XSS happens in the front end, so no execution of server-side code. Losing an access token is one of "THE" problems on the front end. An attacker can then access your APIs and steal users' data.